# Javascript file in theme does not get loaded

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I just added a script `scroll.js`, but it does not get loaded.

My theme is called `test`. I put the script in the `js` directory within the theme directory.

Permissions on the script are `644` (like on all other scripts in other themes) and permissions on the js directory are `755`.

I added a line `scripts[]= js/scroll.js` to `test.info`.

Sorry for forgetting to mention the version of Drupal. I'm using Drupal 7.
I flushed all caches and did a hard refresh in the browser (tried both Firefox and Chromium).

After it looking like nothing was being loaded, I added a line `window.alert("sometext");` to the script just to be sure. Still nothing.

In Firefox and Chrome the file is neither listed as being loaded nor as failing to load or permissions error.

It seems to me that the change to the `.info` file is being ignored, but I might well be wrong. How do I force Drupal to not ignore the new script file?

Comment: The answer is different based on whether you are using Drupal 7 or Drupal 8, you mention the `.info` file so assuming you are on D7?

Comment: Would re-installing your theme help? In my experience this was solved by a simple drupal cache clear.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 8 my theme uses the file main.js. If my theme was called test I would add the file in this order.

File location:

```
test/js/main.js
```

In test.info.yml:

```
libraries:
  - test/global-js
  - test/global-css
```

In libraries.yml:

```
global-js:
  js:
    js/main.js: {}
global-css:
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {}
```

Remember your spacing in the .yml files (2 spaces).
also read [adding stylesheets and javascript to a drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195) and
[Creating a drupal 8 sub-theme, or sub-theme of sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2165673)

Happy Drupaling